# Travis CI Django Build Fails

Tags: python, django, postgresql, travis-ci

For the past few days, I have been working with Travis CI to automatically run my test cases.  However, I cannot get it to work.

Running my test cases locally works great.  I use the command:

```
python manage.py test myApp
```

My travis.yml file is as follows...

```
language: python

os: linux

python:
 - "3.5.2"

services: postgresql


install:

 - pip install -r requirements.txt

script: 

 - python manage.py test myApp
```

I keep getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column myApp_userdocument.createdOn does not exist
```

I have tried running migrate before running the script with no luck. Does anything look blatantly wrong with my travis file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `makemigrations`. Only running migrate won't help you you have to run `makeigrations` as well

```
script: 

 - python manage.py makemigrations
 - python manage.py migrate
 - python manage.py test myApp
```

PS: Only `migrate` will work if you have SQLite database

EDIT: You also need to create a database before you do `makeigrations`

From the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-Builds)

```
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Using-PostgreSQL-in-your-Builds) for setting up postgres and providing credentials.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and will report back!

Comment: I am now getting this error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "Test" does not exist    It looks like a step in the right direction though!

Comment: oh right. You have to also create the database in postgres then run makemigrations. I will update the answer, just a moment.

Comment: Thanks! I'll make the edit, read through the links you sent me and will try again.